# ContentEditable ng-model in ng-repeat not working

Tags: angularjs, html

I am having simple code where user can edit data in contenteditable. for this I've used contenteditable from https://github.com/akatov/angular-contenteditable .
In ng-repeat the ng-model bind process not working. here is my code

```
 <div class="list card listinfo" ng-repeat="(key,dtls)  in ddetails.details">
   <h2 contenteditable="true" ng-model="dtls.title"></h2>
   <p contenteditable="true"  ng-model="dtls.subtitle"></p>
  </div>
```

I have also tried like this

```
   <div class="list card listinfo" ng-repeat="(key,dtls)  in ddetails.details">
      <h2 contenteditable="true" ng-model="ddetails.details[key].title"></h2>
      <p contenteditable="true"  ng-model="ddetails.details[key].subtitle"></p>
  </div>
```

but I am unable to get data.

I am fetching data from firebase

```
$scope.ddetails = FBFactory.getDM($stateParams.ddata);
```

and console output is below,

```
$id: "darjeeling"
$priority: null
details: Object
-KAyw0psnsBBLtnHSeJj: Object
address: ",India"
email: "test@gmail.com"
phone: "+91-"
shortDesc: "Short Description"
subtitle: "Sub Title"
title: "Title"
website: "http://www.google.com"
__proto__: Object
-KB8E8bHM2enqA4VnZkX: Object
-KB8E57BeUsuNw1R4m9E: Object
-KB8E60Pnm1sFCPaFL7I: Object
-KBBUfmzn7Ym6p0O7oQH: Object
-KBBUrCgoBKqKsXB_C4H: Object
__proto__: Object
shortDesc: "work test fdsfds"
title: "Dazzling Dfdfeling"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like (its really named ddetails?):

```
<div class="list card listinfo" ng-repeat="detail in ddetails.details">
      <h2 contenteditable="true" ng-model="detail.title"></h2>
      <p contenteditable="true"  ng-model="detail.subtitle"></p>
  </div>
```

You get for each repeat the whole object and it should be binded to the original array.

Comment: Try {{detail}} inside the ng-repeat to see if there is any data (before the <h2> or something). Maybe your array is just empty or the naming is wrong. Check the array for data. If there is data, try to add 'track by $index' at the end of your ng-repeat expression.

Comment: if I am trying ng-bind-html="dtls.title" data is coming. but it's not binding in ng-model. I have consoled it and data is coming. I also tracked by $index, and key everything is fine.

Comment: Please update your question with the initialization of the array.

Comment: I have already initialized and it's proper using ng-bind-html

Comment: You should show us the code, where you initialize it. I can't see the error in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

As per Angular JS docs. ng-model binds form elements check this [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

Where as ng-bind-html works with any html element [ng-bind-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

Comment: Well here is the code which is working  `<p id="shortDescriptionId" contenteditable="true" ng-model="ddetails.shortDesc" class="item">
                                                
                                            </p>`